# boxturtle tutorials installation error

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-lucid, rosinstall, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed boxturtle on ubuntu 10.04 and I'm receiving the following error when attempting to install the tutorials:

"ERROR: Failed to install tree 'ros_tutorials' using command:
svn co  https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_tutorials/branches/boxturtle /home/user/ros-tutorials/ros-tuturials
Perhaps there is another installation in the way, or there are permissions issues."

Is there a workaround for this or is there a permission I'm missing?  My current permissions for this folder are: drwxr-xr-x

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10780/boxturtle-tutorials-installation-error/) by [wkr101](https://answers.ros.org/users/858/wkr101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-08-01**:
Please note, boxturtle is really old. The current release is Diamondback, and Eturtle is just around the corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the folder already exist? I.e. is it "in the way"?

Then try removing it first. If the permissions are for the parent, it should work.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0